# Cache Dataset in session to fetch on demand

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, delphi, rest

I'm considering using WCF or mormot as frameworks for RESTful service, where the code of business / legacy that needs to be accessed is written in Delphi. Performance is a premise in the project. 
The application must be prepared for load balancing. The clients of REST service Desktops are Windows applications. These desktop clients allow the user to view large volumes of data, with huge resultsets in SQL statements. What is the best way to implement a service to cache a recordset and consume it slowly through the REST service. Can demonstrate a good example? The recordset must be cached in the session until the client completed the consultation or decided to do the full fetch. I'm looking for the right architecture?

Enabling load balancing will work in WCF? Due to the recordset being cached on a single server, with the row fetch requests, if any, must fall on the same server.

Comment: How is your resultset content? Some huge binary blobs, and a lot of simple values rows? What is your database engine you want to use?

Answer (score 3):

Both WCF and *mORMot* share the same high-performance kernel-mode *http.sys* server. Both feature IOCP and multi-threading.

For performance, *mORMot* [will be lighter](http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests/), will allocate (much) less memory, won't be affected by Garbage Collector freezes, and is able to get JSON content directly from the database engine (by-passing most temporary data conversion and allocation) - so that you [can achieve amazing speed](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/03/07/Support-of-MySQL%2C-DB2-and-PostgreSQL). In short, *mORMot* was designed for performance of serving REST/JSON content from the ground up - with a multi-threaded kernel (whereas e.g. node.js is mono-threaded). If your purpose is also to cache some data, *mORMot* works very well as 64 bit native services, giving access to all your system RAM if needed, and has built-in [real-time content compression](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/26/Pure-pascal-LZO-and-SynLZ-compression-units).

WCF is a great general-purpose communication library, which can be RESTful, but is not RESTful from its (historical) roots. The main issue I saw with WCF is the difficulty to configure it between applications (.exe.config tuning may be confusing), and that it is a big black box. For instance, it was not possible to implement [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) with WCF when the server is hosted as a Windows service (the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` HTTP headers are deleted by WCF!): you have to host it within IIS - and can't fix the issue, whereas with a full Open Source solution, you can fix any issue.

Load-balancing can be implemented in *mORMot* and WCF with the same algorithm. Instead of using a round-robbin algorithm in your case, a simple routing based on the content may be enough.

Using WCF to serve business logic written in Delphi will be slow, error prone and difficult to maintain. Mixing technologies induces unneeded complexity. I would not go into this direction.

If you have an existing Delphi code base, and some Delphi skills, I guess *mORMot* may be a better choice. It [was reported](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=9989#p9989) e.g. that a single server on production is able to hande more than one million requests per day, serving thousands of concurrent clients, with [dedicated JavaScript process](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/01/20/Adding-JavaScript-support-to-mORMot) on the server side. One of the *mORMot* design goals was to [help working with existing code and legacy projects](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/12/31/Enhance-existing-projects-with-mORMot). But I'm not 100% fair, since I'm the main maintainer of this open source project. :)